# Extend GWT widget built using UIBinder

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I'm trying to extend a GWT widget that is built using UIBinder. UIBinder expects the fields in ui.xml to be in the extended widget. The problem that was well described by 'Blessed Geek' on [Google Groups](http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/87c9d7397f3fd3eb/668f587fecc027e2).  Any tips/tricks?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

'Blessed Geek' found the right solution here: the caption is in a composition relationship with its panel. As such, it should use a different class (which could be a static inner class to keep things together).

In my experience, inheritance works with UiBinder, as long as your subclass' `ui.xml` file defines all the `ui:field` of its superclass. If it doesn't, then inheritance might not be the right pattern. (Naturally, you can always add fields in your subclass.)